# Is operator evaluation sequence in a SQL Server stored procedure impacted by the client making the call?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

A stored procedure like the below consistently succeeds when called from SQL Server Management Studio (I am running 2012):

```
create procedure MyProc (@myString varchar(10))
as 
begin
    select 
        case 
           when isnumeric(@myString) = 1 AND cast(@myString AS Numeric) > 0
              then 'positive number'
           else 'negative number or non-numeric'
        end AS result
end

exec MyProc 'hello'
```

But if called from C#, the procedure consistently throws a conversion error, failing on the `cast(@myString AS Numeric)`:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure MyProc, Line 5
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

It's as if the left-to-right sequential precedence described here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) together with short circuiting behavior is not followed when the procedure is called from a C# program:

> When two operators in an expression have the same operator precedence level, they are evaluated left to right based on their position in the expression

What would cause this difference in behavior? How might the client calling this stored procedure impact the sequence of AND operator evaluation?

Comment: Operator precedence is different to [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). SQL standard does not define the Short-circuit evaluation and therefore the vendors do not implement it

Comment: Client is irrelevant, that can fail in a variety of scenarios. If you're on an older version that doesn't support `TRY_CONVERT()` then do `CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC() THEN CASE WHEN CONVERT() < 0 THEN ...` but a couple of things, you'll need two `ELSE` fallbacks (but they can now be more specific!), and `ISNUMERIC()` is not the most reliable way to check if something can be converted to a *specific* numeric type. Try `'0d27'`, `'1e99'`, `CHAR(9)`, `'$'`, etc. These all say `ISNUMERIC()=1`. Also, "operators in an expression" ==> those comparisons are two *separate* expressions.

Comment: Thank you.  I am not so much looking for coding advice as I am for an explanation for the consistent successful behavior shown by SSMS vs the fails from C#.  Also, I am not so quick to let Microsoft off the hook regarding the misleading documentation cited.  Anyone looking at that note and trying the example proc in SSMS would be inclined to take the doc at face value if they saw the same degree of consistent success that I saw.  Note the absence of any caveat in that Microsoft note.

Comment: Please disregard my comment above. As @Cha suggests, my earlier description of the issue (which I have revised) was incomplete.  It is the short-circuiting behavior (in conjunction with left-right evaluation) that appears to be client-dependent.

Comment: One more thing...It was premature of me to slam Microsoft's doc.  Left-right evaluation may in fact be occurring consistently as documented. Again, it's the short circuiting...

Answer (score 1):

Use `try_convert()`.  It is much more sensible:

```
create procedure MyProc (@myString varchar(10))
as 
begin
    select (case when try_convert(float, @myString) > 0
                 then 'positive number'
                 else 'negative number or non-numeric'
            end) AS result;
end;

exec MyProc 'hello';
```

I'm not sure why your version would fail.  But, SQL Server does not guarantee the order of evaluation of boolean expressions.

I interpret the documentation that you site as being "logically evaluated".  That is, it explains what the value of `4 - 2 + 27`, but not the actual execution order in the engine.  It doesn't make sense to me that SQL Server would specify evaluation order in this case, given all the other optimizations that it does, and the fact that ANSI doesn't require it.